# Random Error [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] when bot plays music

Tags: javascript, discord.js, ytdl

I have a weird problem, I get this error at random and it occurs when the bot tries to play music that has been added recently or has been in the queue.
You could even then play the same music again and wouldn't get this error.

This is the error I get :

```js
internal/validators.js:117
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument mest be of type string. Recived undefined.
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
    at Url.parse (url.js:159:3)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js.154:13)
    at doDownload (/root/bot/node_modules/miniget/dist/index.js:90:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queue.js:79:11) {
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I don't know how to fix this or what even causes it because this happens randomly.
My code :

```js
client.on ("message", async message => { 

    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    const args = message.content.split(' ');
    const iskanje = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

const musicplay = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Podati moraš link od glasbe oz. ime. Primer :\nplay https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nTTWcHD-D8\n**ali**\nplay psy daddy")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicjoin = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Moraš biti v voice kanalu, da se lahko pridružim.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicskip = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Preskočil sem glasbo.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicskipkanal = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Nisi v kanalu z botom, da bi lahko preskočil glasbo.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicneigra = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Nobena glasba se ne predvaja.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicstop = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Glasba ustavljen...")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

 const musicleave = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Zapustil sem voice kanal.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicleavekanal = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Nisi v kanalu z botom, da bi lahko uporabil to komando.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicleaveigra = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Bot ni v kanalu.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicustavil = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Ustavil sem glasbo.")
    .setThumbnail("https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/pause+circle+outline+24px-131985190736595822.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicustavilježe = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Glasbo sem že ustavil.")
    .setThumbnail("https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/pause+circle+outline+24px-131985190736595822.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicpredvaja = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Glasbo predvajam naprej.")
    .setThumbnail("https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/play+icon-1320183326850327361.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicvolumeštevilka = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Prosim podaj število med 0 - 25.")
    .setThumbnail("https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/255-2559595_volume-up-font-awesome-volume-logo-no-background.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicvolumečrka = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Prosim podaj število med 0 - 25 in ne črko ipd.")
    .setThumbnail("https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/255-2559595_volume-up-font-awesome-volume-logo-no-background.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicpredvajaježe = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Glasba ni ustavljena, da bi jo lahko predvajal naprej.")
    .setThumbnail("https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/play+icon-1320183326850327361.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicnobena = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription("Nobena glasba se ne predvaja.")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicčakalnaigra = new RichEmbed() 
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`Nobena glasba se ne predvaja.`)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_queue_music_48px-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicloopvklop = new RichEmbed() 
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`Vklopil sem zanko.`)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/music-fill/100/Loop-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicloopizklop = new RichEmbed() 
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`Izklopil sem zanko.`)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/music-fill/100/Loop-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const playlistačakalna = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`Čakalna vrsta ne bo prikazana, ker ma discord limti na 2048 črk na sporočilo + ker nočem, da bot crasha, če ma playlista preveč pesmi, ker ne more poslat sporočila.`)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_queue_music_48px-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const searchnič = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`Ni bilo podane številke, zato preklicujem izbiro glasbe.`)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/unicons-vector-icons-pack/32/search-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const searchnull = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`
    Nisi podal imena glasbe, poskusi se enkrat.
    **Primer:** search my oh my`)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/unicons-vector-icons-pack/32/search-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

const musicničnašel = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`
    **Nič nisem našel na podlagi iskalnega niza :** ${iskanje}

    Prosim poskusi še enkrat, če se ta napaka ponavlja, 
    kontaktiraj : Anej#0001
    `)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-2-9/34/85-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

    if(msg.startsWith(`play`)) {
        message.delete();
        if (!iskanje) return message.channel.send(musicplay).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        const url = args[1] ? args[1].replace(/<(.+)>/g, '$1') : '';
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(musicjoin).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });

        if(url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)) {
            const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url);
            const videos = await playlist.getVideos();
            for(const video of Object.values(videos)) {
                const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id);
                await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel, true);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                var video = await youtube.getVideo(url);
            } catch (error) {
                try {
                    var videos = await youtube.searchVideos(iskanje, 1);
                    var video = await youtube.getVideoByID(videos[0].id);
                } catch (err) {
                    return message.channel.send(musicničnašel).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
                }
            }

            return handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel);
        }
    } else if (msg.startsWith(`search`)) {
        message.delete();
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(musicjoin).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (!iskanje) return message.channel.send(searchnull).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });

        var videos = await youtube.searchVideos(iskanje, 10);
        let index = 1;

        const musicsearch = new RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(" Glasba ")
        .setColor(0xFF1E24)
        .setDescription(`
        **Izbira glasbe:**
        ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
        ${videos.map(video2 => `**${index++} -** ${video2.title}`).join(`\n`)}

        ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
        **Podaj številko med 1-10**
                    `)
        .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/unicons-vector-icons-pack/32/search-512.png")
        .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

        message.channel.send(musicsearch).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(10000); });

        try {
            var response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(message2 => message2.content > 0 && message2.content < 11, {
                maxMatches: 1,
                time: 10000,
                errors: ['time']
            });
        } catch (err) {
            return message.channel.send(searchnič).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        }
        const videoIndex = parseInt(response.first().content);
        var video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(videos[videoIndex - 1].id);
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel);

    } else if (msg.startsWith(`skip`)) {
        message.delete();
        if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(musicskipkanal).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(musicneigra).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (serverQueue.loop === true) {
            serverQueue.loop = false;
        }
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
        return undefined;
    } else if (msg.startsWith(`volume`)) {
        message.delete();
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(musicneigra).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(musicleavekanal).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });

        const musicvolumeglastnost = new RichEmbed()
            .setTitle(" Glasba ")
            .setColor(0xFF1E24)
            .setDescription(`Trenutna glastnost : ${serverQueue.volume}`)
            .setThumbnail("https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/255-2559595_volume-up-font-awesome-volume-logo-no-background.png")
            .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send(musicvolumeglastnost).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (args[1] < 0 || args[1] > 25) return message.channel.send(musicvolumeštevilka).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send(musicvolumečrka).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        serverQueue.volume = args[1];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume(args[1] / 5);

        const musicvolumenastavil = new RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(" Glasba ")
        .setColor(0xFF1E24)
        .setDescription(`Natavil sem glastnost na : ${args[1]}`)
        .setThumbnail("https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/255-2559595_volume-up-font-awesome-volume-logo-no-background.png")
        .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

        return message.channel.send(musicvolumenastavil).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
    } else if (msg.startsWith(`leave`)) {
        message.delete();
        let voiceChannel = message.guild.me.voiceChannel;
        if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(musicleavekanal).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (serverQueue) {
            serverQueue.songs = [];
            serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        } else {
            if (voiceChannel) return voiceChannel.leave();
            return message.channel.send(musicleaveigra).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        }
    } else if (msg.startsWith(`queue`)) {
        message.delete();
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(musicčakalnaigra).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        let čakalna = ``;
        for (var i = 1; i < serverQueue.songs.length; i++) {
            čakalna += `**${i}. -** [${serverQueue.songs[i].title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${serverQueue.songs[i].id})\n`;
        }

    const musicčakalna = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24) //${serverQueue.songs.map(song => `**${index++}. -** [${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id})`).join(`\n`)}
    .setDescription(`  
    **Čakalna vrsta:**
    ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
    ${čakalna}
    **Sedaj predvajam:** [${serverQueue.songs[0].title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${serverQueue.songs[0].id})      
                `)
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_queue_music_48px-512.png")
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');
            if (musicčakalna.length < 2024) return message.channel.send(musicčakalna).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
            return message.channel.send(playlistačakalna).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(10000); });

    } else if (msg.startsWith(`pause`)) {
        message.delete();
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(musicneigra).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (!serverQueue.playing) return message.channel.send(musicustavilježe).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (serverQueue && serverQueue.playing) {
        serverQueue.playing = false;
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause();
        return message.channel.send(musicustavil).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        }
        return message.channel.send(musicnobena).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
    } else if (msg.startsWith(`resume`)) {
        message.delete();
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(musicneigra).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (serverQueue.playing) return message.channel.send(musicpredvajaježe).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (serverQueue && !serverQueue.playing) {
            serverQueue.playing = true;
            serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.resume();
            return message.channel.send(musicpredvaja).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
            }
            return message.channel.send(musicnobena).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
    } else if (msg.startsWith(`loop`)) {
        message.delete();
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(musicneigra).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        if (serverQueue.loop === false) {
            serverQueue.loop = true;
            return message.channel.send(musicloopvklop).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        }  else {
            serverQueue.loop = false;
            return message.channel.send(musicloopizklop).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
        }

    }
    return undefined;
});

async function handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    const song = {
        id: video.id,
        title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
        url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`
    };
    if (!serverQueue) {
       const queueConstruct = {
           textChannel: message.channel,
           voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
           connection: null,
           songs: [],
           volume: 5,
           playing: true,
           loop: false
       };
       queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);

       queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

       try {
        var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        queueConstruct.connection = connection;
        play(message.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        queue.delete(message.guild.id);
        return 
    }
} else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);

    const musicqueue = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`GLASBA :
        [${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id})
        je bila dodana v čakalo vrsto!`)
    .setImage(`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${song.id}/hqdefault.jpg`)
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

    if (playlist) return undefined;
    else return message.channel.send(musicqueue).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
}
return undefined;
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) return queue.delete(guild.id);

        const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url), {filter: 'audioonly'})
        .on('end', () => {
            if (serverQueue.loop === true) serverQueue.songs.push(serverQueue.songs.shift());
            else serverQueue.songs.shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        });
    dispatcher.setVolume(1);

    const musicplay = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(" Glasba ")
    .setColor(0xFF1E24)
    .setDescription(`PREDVAJAM GLASBO :
        [${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id})`)
    .setImage(`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${song.id}/hqdefault.jpg`)
    .setFooter('Za izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

        serverQueue.textChannel.send(musicplay).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(5000); });
}



client.login (token);
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I added it in,.

Comment: Thank your for the note, I typed it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install ytdl-core@latest
```

Fixed this issue